# Access related entity properties from user object after registration

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig, fosuserbundle

I have a main `User` entity that holds common fields but also has some extensions like for example `Company` and `Natural` both extends from `User`. Basically (I remove the rest of info since it's not relevant here) this is how my entities looks:

`\UserBundle\Entity\User.php`:

```
class User extends BaseUser
{

    /**
     * @var \Natural
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\UserBundle\Entity\Natural", mappedBy="user")
     */
    protected $natural;

    /**
     * @var \Company
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\UserBundle\Entity\Company", mappedBy="user")
     */
    protected $company;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->natural = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->company = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get natural
     *
     * @return \UserBundle\Entity\Natural
     */
    public function getNatural()
    {
        return $this->natural;
    }
}
```

`\UserBundle\Entity\Company.php`:

```
class Company
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="social_reason", type="string", length=200, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $social_reason;

    /**
     * @var \User
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\UsuarioBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="company")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $user;

    /**
     * Get razon social
     *
     * @return decimal
     */
    public function getSocialReason()
    {
        return $this->social_reason;
    }

    /**
     * Set User
     *
     * @param \UserBundle\Entity\User $user
     * @return Company
     */
    public function setUser(\UserBundle\Entity\User $user = NULL)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get User
     *
     * @return \UserBundle\Entity\User
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }
}
```

`\UserBundle\Entity\Natural.php`:

```
class Natural
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=150)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="lastname", type="string", length=200)
     */
    protected $lastname;

    /**
     * @var \User
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="company")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $user;

    /**
     * Set User
     *
     * @param \UserBundle\Entity\User $user
     * @return Empresa
     */
    public function setUser(\UserBundle\Entity\User $user = NULL)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Get lastname
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function Lastname()
    {
        return $this->lastname;
    }

    /**
     * Get User
     *
     * @return \UserBundle\Entity\User
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }
}
```

Having this relationship between entities, how in `FOSUserBundle:Registration:email.txt.twig` (which is override by me at `\app`) I can access methods from `Natural` entity or `Company` entity? Let's say I need from `Natural` the name `getName` and lastname `getLastName`? Why? Because I need to send extra info on the email sended to Users and that info is stored on that tables when Users got registered, any help?

**Clarifying some things**

- `User`: is a system User from FOSUserBundle
- `Company` and `Natural`: both are extensions of User the difference is which kind of information stores each one, for example a Company may have Social Reason, RIF (some kind of ID number), How many people works on that company, if it's a Regional Company or a main Company and Contact Person (this is not a system user is a normal entity linked just to Company) and a Natural may have a CI (some kind of ID number like DNI on European countries), Name, Lastname, Birthday, Sex and so on. Both Natural and Company shares some properties as for example username, email (canonicalEmail), address, Phone Number and some others, for that reason Company and Natural are linked to User and they can not exists if a User does not exists before

So the process here is:

- Create the user and persist it using UserManager
- Create a Natural/Company entity and set their properties from data in $request and yes this has to be done by hand for that you'll see `setUser()` (which set the current user created before as the FK for Natural/Company) and some others
- Handle the relationship in a N:M entity UserHasService()

Comment: Have you tried $this->natural->getName() from inside your User entity?

Comment: @Doug I tried from the template itself as `user.natural.getName` but I got an empty string with this error `Impossible to access an attribute ("getName") on a NULL variable ("") in FOSUserBundle:Registration:email.txt.twig at line 4` I don't know how to fix this

Comment: Hmmm.  You are using a OneToMany relation between user and natural/company.  So you should have a User::getNaturals() which will return an array.  Perhaps you intended to have a OneToOne relation?

Comment: @Cerad `you should have a User::getNaturals()`, where? In my User entity?

Comment: Yep.  If you really meant to make a one to many relation then natural should be naturals and company should be companies and you need to provide public getters for them.  Do yu understand the difference between ManyToOne and OneToOne?  Might want to go back to basics and review the Product ManyToOne Category relation.  http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#entity-relationships-associations

Comment: Haven't you generated you getters and setters?

Comment: @Cerad `getNaturals()` is not the same as `getNatural` as I have in my `User` entity? I edited the post adding some extra information around this. At DB knowledge level yes, I know the difference between `ManyToOne` and `OneToOne` but the problem is here, since I'm only need to get the related `Natural` or `Company` so should I use a `OneToOne` instead the one I'm using?

Comment: @Doug yes I have it, take a look at the edit I made seconds ago

Comment: @Cerad when a new `User` is created there can be only one of the two entities, I mean I create a user and can be `Natural` or `Company` but not both maybe this help in something

Comment: ManyToOne is not what you want.  I'd have to understand why you are doing this.  You might want a UserCompany or a UserNatural object.  Just depends on what you are trying to do.  Gonna bail now.

Comment: @Cerad can you give me some help with some kind of example? Point me in the right direction? Maybe leave some answer with some help code?

Comment: To help me understand could you explain what a natural is and what a company is. like cerad said what you are doing seems wrong but in order to offer an alternative we'd have to understand what you really wish to achieve.

Comment: @Doug, see my last edition, I added the info you've requested if you have any doubt feel free to ask, I'm stucked in this and don't know how to get this fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming in the Company and Natural entities you do actually have a Name field, also I'm assuming you have getters and setters in all of your entities, including getCompany/getNatural inside your user. Then do the following.

If you set a toString in both Natural and Company like so:

```
public function __toString()
{
    return $this->getName();
}
```

That way in your template all you have to call is:

```
{{ (user.company) }}
```

> > > "Doug I tried from the template itself as user.natural.getName but I got an empty string with this error Impossible to access an attribute ("getName") on a NULL variable ("")"

I think if your calling .getName you might find just removing 'get' could fix it.

Comment: Hi @Doug I added some extra info on main post around entities as for example if you take a closer look `Natural` has `getName` and `getLastname` methods but `Company` has `getSocialReason` so that the difference, so any advice?